# Multiple-step OLEDB Error for SQLSERVER.CE.OLEDB.3.5 Connection

Tags: vb6, sql-server-ce

I am trying to connect to a SQL Server Compact Edition .sdf file with following connection string;

```
connMRC.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.SQLSERVER.CE.OLEDB.3.5;Data Source=" & App.Path & "\Freeweigh.sdf;"
```

I get the following error everytime I try running an SQL command or opening a recordset:

> Multiple-step OLE DB generated errors. Check each OLE DB status value, if available. No work was done.

I am using VB 6.0 and SQL Server Compact 3.5 SP2

Here's the code:

```
Public Sub opnConnectionC()
'Code for opening the ADO Connection
chkConn = connMRC.State
If chkConn = adStateClosed Then
    connMRC.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.SQLSERVER.CE.OLEDB.3.5;Data Source=" & App.Path & "\Freeweigh.sdf;"
    connMRC.Open
End If
End Sub


Public Sub opnRecordsetC(rsOpen As Recordset)
'Code for opening the ADO Recordset
chkRs = rsOpen.State
If chkRs = adStateClosed Then
    rsOpen.Source = strSQLC
    rsOpen.CursorType = adOpenDynamic
    rsOpen.LockType = adLockOptimistic
    rsOpen.ActiveConnection = connMRC
    rsOpen.Open
End If
End Sub


Private Sub tmrUpload_Timer()
Dim cmdUpload As New ADODB.Command
Dim rsFetch As New ADODB.Recordset

Call opnConnectionC

strSQLC = "SELECT Product FROM VehicleWeights"
Call opnRecordsetC(rsFetch)
rsFetch.MoveFirst
MsgBox (rsFetch.Fields("Product").Value)

Call clsConnectionC
End Sub
```

Comment: Not all ADO operations are possible, but PLEASE share some code

Comment: just updated the question with relevant code. Please take a look

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only open a forward only, read only recordset